Primeng carousel duplicate HTML code after setting autoplay Interval props
The carousel duplicate HTML code after setting autoplayInterval props even though I set the numVisible to 1. I'm using PrimeNG v17 on the Angular 17.
The source code:
<p-carousel [value]="testimonials" [numVisible]="3" [numScroll]="1" [circular]="true" [autoplayInterval]="5000"
    orientation="horizontal">
    <ng-template pTemplate="item" let-testimonials>
        <div class="testimonialsCard">
            <div class="testimonialsCardInner">
                <div class="d-flex testimonialsCardTop">
                    <img src="https://t4.ftcdn.net/jpg/03/64/21/11/360_F_364211147_1qgLVxv1Tcq0Ohz3FawUfrtONzz8nq3e.jpg"
                        alt="">
                    <div>
                        <p>Data</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ng-template>
</p-carousel>

The result:
<div ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]" aria-hidden="false" aria-label="0" aria-roledescription="Slide"
    class="p-carousel-item">
    <div _ngcontent-ng-c878305462="" class="**testimonialsCard**">
        <div _ngcontent-ng-c878305462="" class="testimonialsCardInner">
            <div _ngcontent-ng-c878305462="" class="d-flex testimonialsCardTop"><img _ngcontent-ng-c878305462=""
                    src="https://t4.ftcdn.net/jpg/03/64/21/11/360_F_364211147_1qgLVxv1Tcq0Ohz3FawUfrtONzz8nq3e.jpg"
                    alt="">
                <div _ngcontent-ng-c878305462="">
                    <p _ngcontent-ng-c878305462="">Data</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div _ngcontent-ng-c878305462="" class="**testimonialsCard**">
        <div _ngcontent-ng-c878305462="" class="testimonialsCardInner">
            <div _ngcontent-ng-c878305462="" class="d-flex testimonialsCardTop"><img _ngcontent-ng-c878305462=""
                    src="https://t4.ftcdn.net/jpg/03/64/21/11/360_F_364211147_1qgLVxv1Tcq0Ohz3FawUfrtONzz8nq3e.jpg"
                    alt="">
                <div _ngcontent-ng-c878305462="">
                    <p _ngcontent-ng-c878305462="">Data</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  <!--bindings={
    "ng-reflect-ng-template-outlet-context": "[object Object]"
  }-->
</div>

The issue is: that the div named with class testimonialsCard was repeated
the issue
The slide shows 2 rows while it must be one row contains data.
There was no issue if I removed [autoplayInterval]
I have also tried to add it with different types like [autoplayInterval] and autoplayInterval but no effective result.
